# Why on a frictionless incline, a rolling object reaches the bottom slower than an non-rolling object?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

I am really sure if what my physics teacher told me was correct.

But he said, rolling objects has rotational kinetic energy, so not all potential energy they have at the start is converted into translation KE, so v is not as big.
(Forgot to ask him the question I had)

But if can derive rotational KE from translational KE, you can just count either of them twice. So then for a rolling object, you simply just count its translational energy twice. In reality only rolling object has both forms of KE. You can, on paper, convert the translational KE of a non rolling one to rotational KE. But in reality, non rolling objects like a rectangular prism does roll.

Comment: If the incline were frictionless, as your question says, the object would simply slide, not roll. Do you want to edit the title of the question?

Comment: I shouldn't use a comment to answer your question, but it's very simple. An object will roll down slower if part of its KE is rotational, rather than devoted to *forward* motion. After all, you can lift a bicycle wheel off the ground and spin it, so it has plenty of rotational KE, but zero translational KE.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, yea! You are right! You need static friction.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - You've got the right idea, but you've ignored the title. On a frictionless incline, an object's rotation rate will be unchanged, and its rotation rate has no effect on its' velocity. That's for an object with circular cross-section, of course. A rolling cube, for instance, would be entertaining.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, how does anything rotate without static friction?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, how to prove that part of the total potential energy is transformed into rotational KE but not entirely into ranslational KE?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, I am not sure if you can see rotational kinetic the same thing as translational kinetic, because it's formula is derived from that of translational KE.

Comment: @What: As Doeser admitted, the incline is not frictionless. I would edit the title, but I'll leave that to Doeser.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, no I am not sure if something can actually roll on smooth surface?

Comment: @Doeser: First go with intuitive understanding, then work it against the math. Suppose you have a [*Pinewood derby*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinewood_derby) race. Then suppose you have a [*friction motor car*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction_motor) and run it down the track. I hope you can see that the friction motor car will travel very slowly, because all the energy goes into its flywheel.

Comment: @Doeser: Smooth is one thing. Frictionless is another. If the slope is covered with grease, you won't get much rotation, it will all be sliding. Maybe you need to decide what your question is.